# WSO2 ForEach mediator with Gmail Connector

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I’m trying to create a scenario of reading GMAIL inbox.
First I used the ListAllMails operation to get the mail list and then used Foreach mediator to call readMail operation inside a sequence.
My problem is, when using  readMail operation ForEach jumps out of the loop after the first execution and the response from the  readMail operation seems to be empty (according to my setup)

Glad if someone can point what am I doing wrong here and how to correct it?

API:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/gmail" name="gmail" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/listEmails">
        <inSequence>
            <gmail.init>
                <userId>xxxx@gmail.com</userId>
                <accessToken>xxx</accessToken>
                <apiUrl>https://www.googleapis.com/gmail</apiUrl>
                <clientId>xxxx</clientId>
                <clientSecret>xxxx</clientSecret>
            </gmail.init>
            <log description="log_init" level="custom" separator=",">
                <property name="LOG INIT" value="Gmail init success"/>
            </log>
            <gmail.listAllMails>
                <q>*</q>
            </gmail.listAllMails>
            <log description="list_mails" level="custom" separator=",">
                <property name="LOG_LIST_MAILS" value="List mails"/>
                <property expression="//resultSizeEstimate" name="RESULT SIZE"/>
            </log>
            <foreach expression="//messages" id="forEachMail">
                <sequence>
                    <sequence key="read_and_delete"/>
                </sequence>
            </foreach>
            <respond description="response"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>    
</api>
```

read_and_delete sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="read_and_delete" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log description="log_id" level="custom">
        <property expression="//messages/id" name="MESSAGE ID"/>
    </log>
    <property description="id" expression="//messages/id" name="id" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <payloadFactory description="email" media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <init xmlns=""/>
        </format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
    <gmail.readMail>
        <id>{$ctx:id}</id>
        <format>full</format>
    </gmail.readMail>
    <log description="log message" level="custom" separator=",">
        <property expression="//snippet" name="MESSAGE"/>
    </log>
</sequence>
```

Console out:
note that there are 8 mails in the mailbox but foreach loop exits after the first iteration

```
[2019-09-20 08:47:22,016] [micro-integrator]  INFO - LogMediator LOG INIT = Gmail init success
[2019-09-20 08:47:22,051] [micro-integrator]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
[2019-09-20 08:47:22,644] [micro-integrator]  INFO - LogMediator LOG_LIST_MAILS = List mails,RESULT SIZE = 8
[2019-09-20 08:47:22,647] [micro-integrator]  INFO - LogMediator MESSAGE ID = 16d4906cb466ed49
[2019-09-20 08:47:22,682] [micro-integrator]  INFO - LogMediator MESSAGE = 
Carbon Server Micro Integrator Server has shut down...
```

Comment: Since you need to make back-end call (to get the result of the gmail's readMail operation) in each iteration, you have to use Iterate mediator instead of ForEach mediator.

Please find the documentation: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Iterate+Mediator